# Botframework how to authenticate first and than use the token to make graph api calls

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

Auth Dialog:

```
import { ChoicePrompt, DialogSet, DialogTurnStatus, OAuthPrompt, TextPrompt, WaterfallDialog, ComponentDialog } from 'botbuilder-dialogs';
import GraphClient from '../graph-client';

const MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG = 'mainWaterfallDialog';
const OAUTH_PROMPT = 'oAuthPrompt';
const CHOICE_PROMPT = 'choicePrompt';
const TEXT_PROMPT = 'textPrompt';
import moment = require('moment');

class AuthDialog extends ComponentDialog {
    constructor() {
        super('AuthDialog');
        this.addDialog(new ChoicePrompt(CHOICE_PROMPT))
            .addDialog(new OAuthPrompt(OAUTH_PROMPT, {
                connectionName: process.env.ConnectionName,
                text: 'Please login',
                title: 'Login',
                timeout: 300000
            }))
            .addDialog(new TextPrompt(TEXT_PROMPT))
            .addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
                this.promptStep.bind(this),
                this.processStep.bind(this)
            ]));

        this.initialDialogId = MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG;
    }

    /**
     * The run method handles the incoming activity (in the form of a TurnContext) and passes it through the dialog system.
     * If no dialog is active, it will start the default dialog.
     * @param {*} turnContext
     * @param {*} accessor
     */
    public async run(turnContext, accessor) {
        const dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessor);
        dialogSet.add(this);

        const dialogContext = await dialogSet.createContext(turnContext);
        const results = await dialogContext.continueDialog();
        if (results.status === DialogTurnStatus.empty) {
            await dialogContext.beginDialog(this.id);
        }
    }

    public async promptStep(step) {
        return step.beginDialog(OAUTH_PROMPT);
    }

    public async processStep(step) {
        if (step.result) {
            // We do not need to store the token in the bot. When we need the token we can
            // send another prompt. If the token is valid the user will not need to log back in.
            // The token will be available in the Result property of the task.
            const tokenResponse = step.result;
            // If we have the token use the user is authenticated so we may use it to make API calls.
            if (tokenResponse && tokenResponse.token) {
                await step.context.sendActivity(`Logged in.`);
            } else {
                await step.context.sendActivity('something wrong happened.');
            }
        } else {
            await step.context.sendActivity('We couldn\'t log you in. Please try again later.');
        }

        return await step.endDialog();
    }
}

export default AuthDialog;
```

I have a main dailog which is connected to luis and based on the intent recognized it executes corrosponding code:

for ex i have this in some cases:

```
case 'CalendarEvents':
                return stepContext.beginDialog('AuthDialog');
                const calendar = await new GraphClient('token').events();
                let eventsBuilder: string = '';
                // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-for-of
                for (let index = 0; index < calendar.length; index++) {
                    const element = calendar[index];
                    eventsBuilder += '\r\n' + moment(element.start.dateTime).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') + ' - ' + element.subject;
                }
                await step.context.sendActivity(`${eventsBuilder}`);
```

So if the intent is **CalendarEvents** then authenticate and than make some graph api call.

The problem I currently have is that the call to graph api is made before the auth is finished, I would like so first user authenticate and than receives some token and use that token for fetching graph api calls!

any idea how to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the [Graph Auth Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/24.bot-authentication-msgraph). In particular,

1. It gets the token in [MainDialog](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/24.bot-authentication-msgraph/dialogs/mainDialog.js):

```js
return step.beginDialog(OAUTH_PROMPT);

[...]

if (step.result) {
    const tokenResponse = step.result;
    if (tokenResponse && tokenResponse.token) {
        const parts = (step.values.command || '').toLowerCase().split(' ');

        const command = parts[0];

        switch (command) {
        case 'me':
            await OAuthHelpers.listMe(step.context, tokenResponse);
            break;
        case 'send':
            await OAuthHelpers.sendMail(step.context, tokenResponse, parts[1]);
            break;
        case 'recent':
            await OAuthHelpers.listRecentMail(step.context, tokenResponse);
            break;
        default:
            await step.context.sendActivity(`Your token is ${ tokenResponse.token }`);
        }
    }
}

[...]
```

2. Then, [OAuthHelpers](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/24.bot-authentication-msgraph/oAuthHelpers.js) uses the token:

```js
static async sendMail(context, tokenResponse, emailAddress) {
    [...]
    const client = new SimpleGraphClient(tokenResponse.token);
    const me = await client.getMe();

    await client.sendMail(
        emailAddress,
        'Message from a bot!',
        `Hi there! I had this message sent from a bot. - Your friend, ${ me.displayName }`
    );
    await context.sendActivity(`I sent a message to ${ emailAddress } from your account.`);
}
```

This is how the sample works. For you, since you only want to do auth in the Auth dialog, you need to get the token from the user using the Auth dialog, then save it to their UserState, similar to [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/43.complex-dialog/dialogs/mainDialog.js#L53). You can then retrieve their UserState in any dialog and use the token if they have it.

#### Note

You can either use the Graph API through regular HTTP [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) requests, or use the [Graph SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript) like the sample does.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, to me it kinda seems like this is tying together authentication with other stuffs, so basically If could it be possible to somehow when authenticating successfully just return the token and use that token in some other file or after the authentication dialog ends, if u took closely look at my example so I would like to do some calls using graph client sdk in maindialog and not from authenticationDialog, since Authentication dialog I would like to keep it just for authentication purpose and not anything else!

Comment: @Lulxim In that case, you need to get the token from the user using the Auth dialog, then save it to their UserState, similar to [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/43.complex-dialog/dialogs/mainDialog.js#L53). You can then retrieve their UserState in any dialog and use the token if they have it.

Comment: I think this answers my question, thank you, could you modify your answer with the last comment so I can accept it!

Comment: @Lulxim Updated!